How to Implement withTRPC HOC for the Root Component in a Next.js App Directory?
In the given tRPC docs, pages/_app.tsx is to be wrapped with withTRPC HOC like this
import type { AppType } from 'next/app';
import { trpc } from '../utils/trpc';

const MyApp: AppType = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
};

export default trpc.withTRPC(MyApp);

How do i accomplish this in app directory structure?
